# Connect to FTP server with a specific username via the file browser

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, nautilus, ftp

I'm having a bit of trouble with ubuntu 18.04 . I want to connect to a remote ftp folder using the UI. I managed to get it to work for one location by clicking on 'Other locations' and entering the FTP address at the bottom where it says 'Connect to server'. The problem is, now that I have connected once, the username and password seem to be cached. I need to be able to connect to this FTP folder as different users, but Ubuntu never asks for the username again and I don't see anywhere to enter it manually. Is there some way to reset the cache or to force ubuntu to ask for the username and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password is stored in the Seahorse app (search for "keys and passwords" on your app screen). You could remove it from there, or log into the FTP server using a different username. In the file manager, click Ctrl + L (for "location") and type

```
ftp://username@ftp-server
```

It will ask you for the password associated with `username`. You can store it forever (again, in Seahorse) or use it only temporarily.

Once logged in, bookmark the location (it will end up in the side bar), then change the name of the bookmark to include the username. Next time, to login as that user, simply click the bookmark. You can use as many bookmarks (with different usernames) as you like.